# Why am i getting totally different output when using charAt in a conditional operator

Tags: java

I was guessing an output 1 for this code but instead of that i am getting output 49,

The code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "1+21";
        int pos = -1;
        int c;
        c = (++pos < str.length()) ? str.charAt(pos) : -1;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `someCondition ? a : b` is the common type for `a` and `b`. In this case, the common type of `str.charAt(pos)` (a char) and `-1` (an int) is int. That means your `str.charAt(pos)` value is being cast to an int -- basically, being converted to its unicode code point, which in this case is the same as its [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value.

49 is the code point for the character '1'.

If you're trying to get c to be the digit '1', the easiest thing to do is to subtract the code point for '0':

```
c = (++pos < str.length()) ? (str.charAt(pos) - '0') : -1;
```

This works because all of the numbers are sequential in unicode, starting with '0'. By subtracting the value of the char '0' from these -- that is, the int 48 -- you get the value you want:

```
'0' = 48   - 48 = 0
'1' = 49   - 48 = 1
...
'9' = 57   - 48 = 9
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

`charAt` method return the `char` value of the position that you pass. Here you are assigning that to a `int` variable. So that means you are getting the integer representation of particular char value.
In your case

```
int c = "1+21".charAt(0); -> actual char is 1 and the ASCII of that is 49
```